# Detectar o abanar o telemóvel em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, estou com uma duvida, eu tenho um pequeno provedor de Internet Móvel e eu cria criar um jogo em html e javascript que o usuário ao abanar o telemóvel pode receber cartas que mais tarde pode trocar por Internet. Eu já sei como capturar o movimento do telemóvel:

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);
    function handleOrientation(event) {
        var absolute = event.absolute;
        var alpha    = event.alpha;
        var beta     = event.beta;
        var gamma    = event.gamma;
}
```

Mas não sei como realmente desenvolver o algoritmo que detecte o abanar para cima e para baixo do dispositivo e ignore o resto dos movimentos! Alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, veja se este exemplo abaixo te ajuda.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alexgibson/shake.js/master/shake.js"></script>
<script>  
    //Ler evento Chacoalhar
    var shakeEvent = new Shake({threshold: 15});
    shakeEvent.start();
    window.addEventListener('shake', function(){
        alert("Chacoalhado.");
    }, false);

    //Parar Evento Chacoalhar
    function stopShake(){
        shakeEvent.stop();
    }

    //Verifique se o agitar é suportado ou não.
    if(!("ondevicemotion" in window)){alert("Não suportado.");}
</script>
```